# clear:right on float:left div

Tags: css

So I have two divs both using `float:left`, so they appear next to each other. 
If I use `clear:left` on the second div it moves to a new line, how come `clear:right` on the first div doesn't achieve the same thing?

Answer (score 3):

`clear: right` means "clear only right floats".

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, this has been driving me crazy.

Answer (score 0):

To be more precise, the [CSS 2.2 specification](https://drafts.csswg.org/css2/visuren.html#flow-control) says:

> **clear:right** Requires that the top border edge of the box be below the bottom outer edge of any right-floating boxes that resulted from elements earlier in the source document.